# Named Entity recognition relative date

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm using spaCy as NLP library to detect named entities. I want to extract dates and time reference fom the text automatically. For example, capture the date in this sentence: `I will go to the show on 1/1/2020` and detect that `1/1/2020` is a DATE named entity.

But I also want to understand relative time phrases, for example `I will go to the show tomorrow`. `tomorrow` is detected as DATE named entity, but I don't know which time it refers - if today is `1/1/2020` than tomorrow is `1/2/2020`. I want to get the `1/2/2020` directly from the named entity, even if it relative.

I tried to do that manually by created a dictionary, but the date named entities are very wide and I miss them with a static dictionary.

Is there any way to receive the actual time from a relative date named entity?

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25124/resolving-time-in-nlp

Comment: Hello, what have you tried? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a quicker response. Also, take some time to review ["Named Entity Recognition"](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities) in spaCy, as it sounds like a potential solution for you.

Comment: @APhillips, I didn't try anything except of string compare of specific words like "tomorrow" or "today". I have already saw that docs of spaCy but there is nothing about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `dateparser` library. [Link to Docs](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```py
pip install dateparser
```

Example:

```py
from dateparser import parse
from dateparser.search import search_dates

print(parse('Tomorrow'))
print(parse('01/01/20'))
print(search_dates("I will go to the show tomorrow"))
print(search_dates("The client arrived to the office for the first time in March 3rd, 2004 and got serviced, after a couple of months, on May 6th 2004, the customer returned indicating a defect on the part"))
```

**output**:

```py
2020-01-30 21:03:17.551187
2020-01-01 00:00:00
[('tomorrow', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 21, 6, 19, 545368))]
[('in March 3rd, 2004 and', datetime.datetime(2004, 3, 3, 0, 0)), 
 ('on May 6th 2004', datetime.datetime(2004, 5, 6, 0, 0))]
```

Comment: It works pretty well, but it miss some "durations" line "one day" - "I can do that in one day"